# Unsuccessful logins with PHP

Tags: php

So when the user unsuccessfully logs in for the first time it performs the tasks 70-73
and then it jumps down to 111. That part works correctly however when the chances left gets to 0 meaning the failedLogins value in the db would be 5 its supposed to do the steps starting at line 76 but it doesn't. Instead it shows 0 for the chances left and then that's it. I'm sure my logic is right but the the code is just placed in the wrong places. (http://pastebin.com/p3n1Fr78)

```
// User is registered and verified
$query = "SELECT * FROM manager_users_logins_hacking WHERE userID = '".$userID."'";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

$lockDate = $row['lockDate'];

// Find out if user is locked out of their account
if (($lockDate !== "0000-00-00 00:00:00") AND (strtotime($lockDate) <= time())) {

    $currentDateTime = time();
    $minutes = floor(($currentDateTime-$lockDate) / 60);

    // Take minutes and perform tasks
    if ($lockDate > 0 && $minutes < 10) {

        // Calculate time remaining
        $timeRemaining = 10 - $minutes;

        // Account locked error
        $output = array('errorsExist' => true, 'message' => 'Your account is currently locked, we appologize for the inconvienence. You must wait ' .$timeRemaining.' minutes before you can log in again!');

    } else {

        // Clear the lock
        $query = "UPDATE manager_users_logins_hacking SET lockDate = NULL, hackerIPAddress = NULL, failedLogins = 0 WHERE userID = '".$userID."'";
        $result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query);

    } 

} else {

    // Escape post data
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$_POST['password']);

    // Assign hashed password to variable
    $regenFromPostPW = reGenPassHash($password, $passwordDB2);

    // Comparing the database password with the posted password
    if ($passwordDB == $regenFromPostPW) {

        $query2 = "UPDATE manager_users_logins SET numberOfLogins = numberOfLogins + 1, lastOnline = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE userID = '".$userID."'";
        $result2 = mysqli_query($dbc,$query2);

        // Assign user data into an array
        $loggedinUserDataArray = array('userID' => $userID, 'name' => $firstName . " " . $lastName);

        // Assign user data array to new session
        $_SESSION['user_data'] = $loggedinUserDataArray;

        // See if the remember me checkbox was checked
        if (isset($_POST['remember'])) {

            // Sets an expiration time for the cookie
            $myExpiration = time()+60*60*24*100;

            // Sets the cookie for the username
            setcookie("username", $username, $myExiration, "/");

        }

        // Succesful login complete
        $output = array('errorsExist' => false, 'message' => 'You have been logged in, please allow a moment while we load your account data!');

    } else {

        // Login unsuccessful

        $query = "SELECT * FROM manager_users_logins_hacking WHERE userID = '".$userID."'";
        $result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        $failedLogins = $row['failedLogins'];

        // Take failed logins and compare it 
        if ($row['failedLogins'] >= 5) {

            // Retrieve IP Address of user trying to hack into account
            $hackerIPAddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

            // Update database after account getting hacked and run query
            $query = "UPDATE manager_users_logins_hacking SET lockDate = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, hackerIPAddress = '".$hackerIPAddress."' WHERE userID = '".$userID."'";
            $result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query);

            $query2 = "SELECT * FROM manager_users WHERE userID = '".$userID."'";
            $result2 = mysqli_query($dbc,$query2);
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2);
            $firstName = $row['firstName'];
            $lastName = $row['lastName'];

            // Email user new registration account
            function my_domain_name() {
                $my_domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
                $my_domain = str_replace('www.', '', $my_domain);
                return $my_domain;
            }
            $sender_email = "noreply@kansasoutlawwrestling.com";
            $reply_to = "noreply@kansasoutlawwrestling.com";
            $recipient_email = $email; 
            $email_subject = "KOW Manager Account Locked";

            $email_body = 'Hello '.$firstName.' '.$lastName.' You, or someone using your account at '.my_domain_name().', has attempted to hack into your account. If this is an error, ignore this email and you will be removed from our mailing list.<br /><br />Regards, '.my_domain_name().' Team';

            mailSomeone($email, $sender_email, $email_subject, $email_body);

            // Account locked error
            $output = array('errorsExist' => true, 'message' => 'Your account is currently locked, we appologize for the inconvienence. This is a security messure implimented by to many failed login\'s! You must wait 10 minutes before you can login again!');         

        } else {

            $query = "UPDATE manager_users_logins_hacking SET failedLogins = '".$failedLogins."'+ 1 WHERE userID = '".$userID."'";
            $result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query);

            $query2 = "SELECT * FROM manager_users_logins_hacking WHERE userID = '".$userID."'";
            $result2 = mysqli_query($dbc,$query2);
            $row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2);
            $failedLogins = $row2['failedLogins'];

            // Calculate how many chances the user has to login before account gets locked
            $chancesLeft = 5 - $failedLogins;

            // Invalid username and password error 
            $output = array('errorsExist' => true, 'message' => 'Invalid Username and Password combination! You have ' .$chancesLeft.' chances left to login succesfully or the account will be locked!'); 

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: hold on, I'm counting line numbers in your source so I can see what you're referring to...

Comment: i had put in a link to the pastebin  http://pastebin.com/p3n1Fr78 that was weird

Comment: That's a helluva wall of text... can't you distill it down to something simpler?

Comment: Your pastebin link will expire and ask your question in words not lines.

Comment: Are you sure that `$row['failedLogins']` is even returning a value?

Comment: Belongs on [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: i'll post it there thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, some things:

If you do not have a defective version of PHP, the number $failedLogins is *not* incrementing to 5 between lines 76 `if($row['failedLogins']>=5)` and line 111 (`$query = "UPDATE manager_users_logins_hacking...`). If it hits line 77, it cannot increment.

That said, it also cannot decrement, so I suggest you might want to consider adding logic to set the count to 0.

You also might be seeing `$chancesLeft` and expecting it to be `$failedLogins` (an all-too-common problem, unfortunately, I've done my share of head-desks because of that).

Also:

First: Are you sure you have error reporting set to maximum?
Second, conditional functions are bad:

```
function my_domain_name() {
    $my_domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    $my_domain = str_replace('www.', '', $my_domain);
    return $my_domain;
}
```

It is best to define your function *outside* of the if block. Even if you only use it once.
Third, you really should only show the immediately relevant code in your questions and try to format so that it is easy to read.
Forth, I see a lot of `'".$variable".`. You may want to make those `"UPDATE...$variable..."` or you should escape a single quote -- `UPDATE ... SET FOO = \''.$foo.'\' WHERE...`. `"` means, "parse this string" and I know that I, for one, expect that it will contain some variable.

Comment: It is doing the increment on the failedLogins 111. I know this because I'm looking at the failedLogins field in the db.

Comment: It may hit line 111, but it is absolutely, beyond any shadow of a doubt, not going to both line 78 and line 111 with a standard PHP install. So, either you are using a version of PHP where `if` doesn't work correctly, or it is not hitting that line.

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = "UPDATE manager_users_logins_hacking SET failedLogins = '".$failedLogins."'+ 1 WHERE userID = '".$userID."'";
```

Isnt failedLogins a number and not a string? so i think you need to get rid of the quotes

Comment: Okay thanks however its not even doing the tasks on the if statement on 76.

Comment: Yes, but isnt the $failedlogins is incremented from 0 to 5 by the statement 111